# My wordpress blog posts do not load after I moved it to the VPS

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, wordpress, lamp

I transferred one of my wordpress blog from shared hosting to VPS. I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps) to install wordpress and [this tutorial](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/website-transfers/how-to-transfer-your-wordpress-blog-from-one-host-to-another-host) to move my site.

After I transferred my site example.com is loading nicely but example.com/mypost/ do not load. It says the "The requested URL /mypost/ was not found on this server."

In my admin panel, I checked the post and they are present there as published. So I checked the apache error.log . It showed the error "File does not exist: /var/www/example/mypost, referer: http://example.com/"

I don't have any idea how to proceed to solve this problem. Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: It could be a problem with .htaccess rewrite. Try to add to your apache AllowOverride All http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Comment: I added AllowOverride All to my virtual host configuration, it still do not load.

Comment: you need mod_rewrite of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of permalinks. I followed [this guide](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache2-on-debian-ubuntu.html) and the problem solved.